# Redirect to custom login page by auth middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes

Without generating Laravel default auth controllers, I create my own login and registration controller.

My routes look like these

**For Login**

```
GET   /login   ->> SessionController@create -->name = login.create
POST  /login   ->> SessionController@store -->name = login.store
```

**For Registration**

```
GET     /registration   ->> RegistrationController@create  -->name = register.create
POST    /registration   ->> RegistrationController@store   -->name = register.store
```

Everything is fine. Now I need one thing.  Whenever I put `auth` middleware, a non-authenticated user will be redirected to my custom login page route to `login.create`.

**How to do this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend `Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate` middleware or just add a new middleware:

```
class AuthMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (auth()->guest()) {
            return redirect()->route('login.create');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Register it in `App\Http\Kernel.php`:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth.custom' => \App\Http\Middleware\AuthMiddleware::class,
    ....
```

And use:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth.custom'], function () {
    // Protected routes.
});
```

Comment: what is "if (auth()->guest()) { " in your code ? how can i check login details is correct or not in middleware ?

Comment: @Camit1dk `auth()->guest()` returns `true` when user is not authenticated.

Comment: I followed your wat to extend the Middleware class and pass a route: [admin/login] but always I get Route not defined even my route is already defined in web.php. Any clue on that? Thanks